# Update in Mysql doesn't update

Tags: php, mysql

I Made this Code For My Profile System it's update a data when user click in " zr "

but no result it's just print " Update Finish!" but in phpmyadmin it's not update

```
    if ($count == 1) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_username)) { 
echo '
<!-- Sample Container -->
<form action="#" method="post">
<h3>Update Profile : '.$row['user'].' <br/> ID: '.$row['id'].'</h3>
<hr/>
<br/>
  <p><input type="text" name="site"/ value="'.$row['site'].'"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="pic"/ value="'.$row['avatar'].'"></p>
      <p><input type="text" name="email"/ value="'.$row['email'].'"></p>
       <p><input type="text" name="cover"/ placeholder="Cover Profile"></p>
       <p><input type="text" name="color"/ placeholder="Flat Background"></p>
  <p><input disabled type="text" value="(Disabled field)"/></p>
  <br/>
  <hr/>
  <input type="submit" name="zr" value="Update / Edit" />
</form>
';



if(isset($_POST['zr'])){

$sql = "UPDATE users SET site='".$row['site']."', avatar='".$row['avatar']."' WHERE id='$username'" ;
$queryedit = mysql_query($sql);
if ($queryedit){

    echo 'Update Finish!';
}    

}
}
}
else
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: Show more code,how is $row formed.

Comment: I just leave the **don't use the mysql_* functions anymore** message here.

Comment: @TobiasXy it's just a test ver when i finish i update code to mysqli func

Comment: `$username` is defined where *exactly?*

Comment: it's $_GET['id'] @Fred-ii-

Comment: ok... now where is `$_GET['id']` coming from? *lol* is this going to be a game of  *22 questions?*

Comment: ask the guy http://stackoverflow.com/a/35798641/ who gave you an answer below or the other one now. I can't keep on commenting here.

Comment: Do your `<h3>Update Profile : '.$row['user'].'...` code show the user and id? Can you show the code where you set the sql for `$check_username`? Can you echo out `$sql` before you `mysql_query($sql)` to insure that `$row['site']` and similar variables are matching your expectations?

Comment: *Here:* Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. Also `var_dump()` and view your HTML source. Those are additional "tools" ;-)

Comment: no no it's not $username it's not empty this is not full code

Comment: and i get answer thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you have $row data in your update query? You want update from form inputs, dont you?

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET site='".$_POST['site']."', avatar='".$_POST['avatar']."' WHERE id='$username'" ;
```